# Query JOIN with multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables with name

*attendance_schedules*

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-20 |
| 2 | 2022-12-21 |
| 3 | 2022-12-22 |

*users*

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Doe |
| 3 | Jonathan Doe |
| 4 | Jennifer Doe |

Then I create a relationship between the two in the table, aiming to list planned attendance and actual attendance.

*attendance_planned*

| attendance_schedule_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

*attendance_actual*

| attendance_schedule_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |

Well, now I want to display combined data between *attendance_schedules*, *attendance_planned*, *attendance_actual* and *users* with *JOIN* on MySQL. But I'm stuck and I can't find references to make what I want happen.

*this is the first time I ask, if there is something that needs to be fixed regarding the title or question, I will be happy to fix it :)

I use this SQL query:

```
SELECT attendance_schedules.date, planning_users.name, actual_users.name
FROM attendance_schedules
LEFT JOIN attendance_planned ON attendance_planned.attendance_schedule_id = attendance_schedules.id
LEFT JOIN users as planning_users ON planning_users.id = attendance_planned.user_id
LEFT JOIN attendance_actual ON attendance_actual.attendance_schedule_id = attendance_schedules.id
LEFT JOIN users as actual_users ON actual_users.id = attendance_actual.user_id
```

Result i want:

| Date | planning_name | actual_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-20 | John Doe | John Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jane Doe | Jane Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jonathan Doe | Jonathan Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | null | Jennifer Doe |
| 2022-12-21 | John Doe | John Doe |
| 2022-12-21 | Jonathan Doe | Jane Doe |
| 2022-12-21 | Jennifer Doe | Jonathan Doe |
| 2022-12-22 | John Doe | Jane Doe |
| 2022-12-22 | Jane Doe | null |

Result happened now:

| Date | planning_name | actual_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-20 | John Doe | John Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | John Doe | Jane Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | John Doe | Jonathan Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jane Doe | John Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jane Doe | Jane Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jane Doe | Jonathan Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jonathan Doe | John Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jonathan Doe | Jane Doe |
| 2022-12-20 | Jonathan Doe | Jonathan Doe |
| .... | .... | .... |

Comment: You're making a cross product between all the actual and planned rows with the same attendance ID.

Comment: The logic of your desired output isn't clear. How do you determine which planning name and actual name should be paired up?

Answer (score 0):

[How to join two tables with unequal number of rows for same primary key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907029/how-to-join-two-tables-with-unequal-number-of-rows-for-same-primary-key-value)

That's likely the problem you encountered.